# How to style a particular selector select for specific media query without wrapping the selector inside @media {..}?

Tags: css, media-queries

How to style a particular selector select for specific media query without wrapping the selector inside `@media {..}`?

Is it possible like

```
.contact-info {float:left}

.contact-info for media screen and max-width 320px {float:none}
```

Comment: I found something like i was asking but it uses JavaScript http://blog.andyhume.net/responsive-containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it's not possible**. For that type of functionality Media Query is best because Media Query is created to solve that purpose. Media Query is the only solution with CSS.

Comment: Not sure what you're really getting at here. He *is* trying to use media queries.

Comment: @BoltClock - No I know about media query. I'm asking to use media query with selector.